# Unable to join javascript array with custom separator

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's the code:

```
var list = ['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'John'];
var words = list.join(' '); // This is a whitespace char
```

What comes out is:

```
"Hello,my,name,is,John"
```

I understand that the default separator is a comma, but I am providing a whitespace as my separator. Why isn't it using the space to separate the words?

Comment: Seems to be working for me: `['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'John'].join(' ') ->
"hello my name is John"`

Comment: What do you get when you paste that code into the console?

Comment: If I log `words` I get the above...

Comment: No, you don't. http://puu.sh/jdQFC.png

Answer (score 3):

Your code assigns the joined string to a different variable `words`. In your code, you probably use the array `list` itself. If you cast an array to string, it also joins the values, but using a comma as the default join character, as you can see in the snippet below:

```js
var list = ['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'John'];
var words = list.join(' '); // This is a whitespace char


alert(words); // hello my name is John
alert(list);  // hello,my,name,is,John
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of give me the result

```
var list = ['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'John'];
var words = list.join().replace(/,/g," ");

alert(words);
```